# How do I load a ui in pyqt using a string

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to load a UI with PyQt but saving the "data" in a string, like, save XML data in a string, to use loadUi()

Example:

```
template = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>... (and more code)
'''
```

So, actually I'm using this code:

```
class Install(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Install, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi(template, self)
```

Comment: Might I ask you why do you need this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `io.StringIO()`:

```py
import io
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic


template = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>28</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>"""


class Install(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Install, self).__init__()

        f = io.StringIO(template)
        uic.loadUi(f, self)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    install = Install()
    install.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Funny, I was going to post almost the same code, including the `f` variable name! :-D By the way, it's worth noticing that it's *very* important to **not** have any character at the very beginning of the UI string, since the `<?xml ...>` declaration *MUST* start at the first character of the string (no spaces, no new lines, no nothing), otherwise an `ElementTree.ParseError` would be raised.

Comment: @musicamante But that's obvious, and my code shows a clear example of that so I don't see the need to mention it.

Comment: I would point out that observation but provide a workable example (for example if I only put `f = io.StringIO(template)` `uic.loadUi(f, self)`) but in this case I don't see the need to point that out.

Comment: that's obvious as long as you know it. Honestly, I didn't know that (I naively thought that any space/new line character was automatically ignored as [x]html parsers do). Considering that we don't really know how the OP is going to create the final XML content (and the amount of knowledge or experience with XML conventions), I believe that it's still worth mentioning (I know it's a simple issue to solve, but, it's also an important thing to be aware of, in any case).

Comment: @musicamante As you point out, the severity of the parse depends on the standard. In HTML, for example, empty lines are acceptable but XML is stricter, so it requires that there are no spaces.